# Swipe to delete in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble to Design my swipe to delete in flutter for my todo app
this is what I have tried:

```
                              Container(
                                   width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.90,
                                   child:Card(
                                          elevation: 0,
                                          color: Colors.transparent,
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                          ),
                                          child: Slidable(
                                            secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                                              SlideAction(
                                                  
                                                  child: Container(
                                                width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .width *
                                                    0.50,
                                                height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .height *
                                                    0.13,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                ),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  'Delete',
                                                ),
                                              ))
                                            ],
                                            actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                                            child:Card(child:Text('Delete')
)
```

and it currently looks like this:

[What it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzo8r.jpg)

but I want it to look like this:
[Wanted to-do app design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSEW7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 you can try change action:SlidableScrollActionPane().There are few 
 other option available .
```

2nd solution change background according to your design

```
Dismissible(                                            
       key: Key(UniqueKey().toString()),
        direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
        onDismissed: (direction) {                                                  
        },
        background: Container(

            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
              
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0,  width*0.02, 0.0),
                  child: new SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/images/delete.svg',
                    height: width*0.05,
                    width:  width*0.05,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, width*0.05, 0.0),
               
                  child: Text(
                    "Delete".toUpperCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
        child:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using dismissible widget with confirmation parameter. Let me if the below code helps in anyway

```
   Dismissible(
   background: Container(color: Colors.red),
   key: Key(item),
   onDismissed: (direction) {
   setState(() {
   items.removeAt(index);
   });

   Scaffold
    .of(context)
    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$item dismissed")));
   },
   child: ListTile(title: Text('$item')),
   );
```